# Select a range using MySQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

So I have this game database, where I have several users with fields, id, name, points

I need a rank table for a specific user where its position can be seen in relation to the amount of points, there is room for 8 positions in the table, so I was looking for a way to do the following:

if I do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {user_id} ORDER By points` Select the 4 results before and the 3 results after this id. is there a query to do this? the result should look like:

```
---------------------
|id   |name  |points|
---------------------
| 52  |name1 | 10   |
---------------------
| 23  |name1 | 09   |
---------------------
| 93  |name1 | 08   |
---------------------
| 12  |name1 | 07   |
---------------------
| 43  |queried_name1 | 06   |
---------------------
| 67  |name1 | 05   |
---------------------
| 32  |name1 | 04   |
---------------------
| 91  |name1 | 03   |
---------------------
```

I was trying to make this by software but it is pretty slow to iterate trough all the results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: before and after part..can u plz elaborate,
You can use union for your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that, I would say, for the above results:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}) ORDER By points ASC LIMIT 3;
```

For the below results:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE points < (SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}) ORDER By points DESC LIMIT 4;
```

So, with a big union, it would give:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}) ORDER By points ASC LIMIT 3 ) a 
UNION
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}
UNION
SELECT * FROM (    SELECT * FROM users WHERE points < (SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {user_id}) ORDER By points DESC LIMIT 4 ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query -

```
SELECT id, name, points FROM (
  SELECT u.*, @r:=@r+1 rank, @pos:=IF(@pos = 0 AND name = 'queried_name1', @r, @pos)
    FROM users u,
    (SELECT @r:=0, @pos:=0) t
  ORDER BY points DESC
  ) t
WHERE rank BETWEEN @pos - 4 AND @pos + 3
```

It ranks table by points, finds a record with name = 'queried_name1', and selects some rows before and after the found record.